# JSch - No progress after SSH_MSG_KEXINIT is sent

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

Simple Java app using JSch (0.1.55) library to connect to SFTP server.
Hangs at the key exchange step after SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent. Logging below.

Code fails on Windows test machine which **is** able to connect with same creds using WinSCP.
Same code also fails on Linux Docker container where we originally found the problem.
Same creds work fine as long as we aren't using JSch library.

We've tried restricting to different kex settings in the config properties but none made any difference.
Up until a month or so ago, we were able to connect to this server without issues, and continue to connect to others with same code.

Simplified code for testing

```java
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        java.util.Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentication", "password,keyboard-interactive");

        try {
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect(30 * 1000);
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            myLog(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Any ideas?

```
Fri Mar 17 15:07:12 EDT 2023 - Connecting to ****.*******.com port 22  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - Connection established  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.3.2.155  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:13 EDT 2023 - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:43 EDT 2023 - Disconnecting from ****.********.com port 22  
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:64978', transport: 'socket'
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64967', transport: 'socket'  
Fri Mar 17 15:07:55 EDT 2023 - Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Comment: Have you tried jsch fork from https://github.com/mwiede/jsch?

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann - Excellent suggestion, thank you!
I tried the fork lib, and with a bit of tweaking - added "ssh-rsa" to server_host_key property, I was able to connect and get a directory listing. 
The logging from this library is also much better than original.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem here - the key was googling the server software: "SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.3.2.155". Doing that led me to this support page from the publisher: https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/SFTP-connection-not-established-for-legacy-Java-clients?language=en_US

Bottom line is that this particular server software just became more strict on clients' adherence to the RFC:

> The Java client doesn't follow the protocol version exchange correctly. According to RFC ft-ietf-secsh-transport: The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol, “The identification MUST be terminated by a single Carriage Return (CR) and a single Line Feed (LF) character 2 (ASCII 13 and 10, respectively)” (content provided by Ylonen & Lonvick, available at https://datatracker.ietf.org/, obtained on January 12, 2023).

> The client identification string SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54 does not contain a CR symbol, which is mandatory according to the RFC.

It goes on to say that the only resolution (assuming you don't control the server itself) is to upgrade to the Matthias' JSch fork (or switch to another library altogether).

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jsch 1.55 source code and apply a fix, then build a new jar file.  The bug is in Session.java.  Search for "Cisco" in the code and then change the code block to this:

```
{
    // Some Cisco devices will miss to read '\n' if it is sent separately.
    byte[] foo = new byte[V_C.length + 2];
    System.arraycopy(V_C, 0, foo, 0, V_C.length);
    foo[foo.length - 2] = (byte) '\r';
    foo[foo.length - 1] = (byte) '\n';
    io.put(foo, 0, foo.length);
}
```

As @Tyler Cunnion mentioned, jsch was not correctly sending CR + LF after identifying itself.  I've also seen an additional fix where you change the identify string from "SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.55" to "SSH-2.0-JSCH_0.1.54" (underscore instead of hyphen near the end).  With these corrections, the jsch library should connect.